# Serialize a function in C

Tags: c, function, serialization, struct, generic-programming

I would like to know if it is possible to serialize a (C-written) function in the C programming language. The context is the following: I have a binary search tree of key-value pairs. The keys are standard null-terminated strings, and the values are of the following type:

```
typedef struct generic_value{

  void *val;
  void (*free_value)(void *);
  void (*write_value)(void *,FILE *);
  void *(*read_value)(FILE *);
  datatype type;
}generic_value;
```

Essentially, the node values contain a pointer to a core data set (void *val), as well as pointers to support functions to write/read the core data to and from file, as well as a deallocation function that knows how to deallocate the core data. At present, the above struct also contains an additional enum type (datatype) to describe the type of the core data:

```
typedef enum{
  integer_t,decimal_t,string_t,complex_t,vector_t,matrix_t
}datatype;
```

I would like to know how to serialize the functions pointed by these struct members (e.g. their executable code), such that when the BST is written to file, it can then be subsequently imported back into memory without knowledge of these functions -- their executable code would first be read in, and the read_value() function would then be called in order to import the core data back into void *val; this would thus obviate the need of the "datatype" member. Is this at all possible in C?

Comment: *"Is this at all possible in C?"* ***No.***

Comment: This might be possible under some OS's, but it wouldn't be portable, and it would be very insecure -- all a miscreant would need to do to get his evil code running in your program is to write a "special" save file and get a victim to load it.  Are you sure you want to do this (as opposed to just, say, writing the function's name into the file and reading the name back in later and doing a lookup in a table to find the corresponding compiled-in function with that name?)

Comment: It's because the set of types my BST can accept is finite, as defined by the API. For example, if a user says: "I want to be able to store string array (char **) into your tree, along with all the other types." then I would have to hard-code this extra functionality by hand into the API, as opposed to letting the user provide his own read/write/dealloc functions that the tree can then use in order to read/write itself or to deallocate its memory. Still curious to know if it could be possible though, and therefore I really appreciate your response!

Comment: if you want to around functions as data, you're going to need to embed an interpreter.  A lot of people use lua and lua scripts.

Comment: A shared library is essentially a serialized collection of functions indexed by name. So serialize the names, and link them at runtime to a shared library.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, and to J. Bollinger below for the extra insight. My workaround solution is to have a map setup with basic types (type strings mapped to utility functions enclosed into a struct). The user can register a new type by simply giving it a name (key) and providing the free/read/write functions which are then encapsulated into a value for the map. So this way the system is extensible to new types. In addition I have also implemented recursion such that another data type is the tree itself, making it possible to create a meta-tree of data containing other data trees

Answer (score 1):

Standard C provides no mechanism to treat code as data or data as code.  Moreover, most modern memory management units and operating systems distinguish between memory designated for data and memory designated for executable code, and they do not allow jumps into the former.  And even if they did not, you have linkage problems unless the functions you propose to serialize are completely self-contained, with no reliance on any other function, including standard library functions.  So no, you cannot serialize functions.

If you want to be able to call functions that were not originally linked into your application, then you're going to need to need to link in a shared library at run time.  In the POSIX world, you would be looking mainly for `dlopen()` to link in the library and `dlsym()` to obtain pointers to the required functions.  That the latter takes the function name as one argument points directly to a serialization strategy that could work with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is quite possible, get rid of the "generic-programming" though. You will have to dive into executable formats. It's not going to work if you just take the code and write it into file. You will have to do some calculations and store some additional information with it, that'll be used for slight initialization when you load the code. Sooo yes this can be done in C. It's not about the language though.. Google ELF and PE.